# is it possible to pass a function with 2 parameters as parameter for another function in java 8/11?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, functional-interface

I have this problem.

I am working with some generics and at one point I will need a specific converted depending on each type.

So, so far I have this:

```
public static <T> List<T> myMethod(List<T> list1, List2<T>, SomeFunction converter) { 
//... do suff
return converter.convert(list1, list2);

}
```

and converter would be like this:

```
public <T> List<T> converter(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
/// cast and do stuff)
return List<T> some stuff;
}
```

Then I would like to make a call like

```
myMethod<list1,list2,converter);
```

I know about the functional internface `Function` but I need to send two parameters for this, is there any way I could do it in Java8/11?

Ideas?

Comment: Instead of Function<T,R> you could use BiFunction<T,U,R>

Comment: could you pleae give me an example? sorry about it but Im not good using this interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [`BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) which represents an operation upon two operands of the same type, producing a result of the same type as the operands.

```
public static <T> List<T> someMethodName(List<T> list1, List<T> list2,  
             BinaryOperator<List<T>> converter) { 
    return converter.apply(list1, list2);
}
```

[`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) is also another option as it represents a function that accepts two arguments and produces a result.

```
public static <T, R> List<R> someMethodName(List<T> list1, List<T> list2,
            BiFunction<List<T>, List<T>, List<R>> converter) {
    return converter.apply(list1, list2);
}
```

To call the function let's assume you have two Integer lists for example sakes:

```
List<Integer> first = ....
List<Integer> second = ....
```

and you wanted to concatenate them, you'd pass both lists and a behaviour e.g.

```
List<Integer> concat = someMethodName(first, second, 
                       (l, r) -> Stream.concat(l.stream(), r.stream())
                       .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Convention would dictate to have the result type be called `R`, so `<R> List<R> (List<T> list1, List<T>, 
            BiFunction<List<T>,List<T>, List<R>> converter)` which would also add flexibility.

Comment: @daniu Very good point (I never bear that in mind) - although type parameters would have to be declared as `<T, R>`

Comment: could you please give me an example of how the function to override the converter.apply would look like? I am a little bit lost :s

Comment: Thanks! I will modify it for my purpose, hopefully it can fit! :)

Comment: @jpganz18 it should fit as long as the function you provide meets the function descriptors of the aforementioned functional interfaces i.e. `(l, r) -> ...` and you're welcome ;-)

Comment: I think it doesnt fit my needs (or I dont know how to make it fit) and I also think my converter needs to return an int, which could cause problems, but the answer of how to use the implementation is just great :)

Comment: @jpganz18 for this specific question, I believe it solves the problem at hand, but feel free to post a new question if you're struggling with something you're working on. provided you've made an attempt along with a good description I am sure people on the site would be happy to help. good luck.

Comment: @Aomine what I now dont understand is ... in the example you pass the third parameter (that is a BiFunction<List<T>, List<T>, List<R>> ...) like this  (l, r) -> Stream.concat(l.stream(), r.stream())
                       .collect(Collectors.toList()) ... how can I pass a method's name instead and how to declare that method? :s

Comment: @jpganz18 the method must have the signature `static List<Integer> xxx(List<Integer> l, List<Integer> r) { ... }` and then you'd be able to use a method reference and pass `Main::xxx` where `Main` is the class containing the `xxx` method, alternatively you could define an inline function such as `BinaryOperator<List<Integer>> function = (l, r) -> ....` and then you'd be able to do `List<Integer> concat = someMethodName(first, second, function);`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your function take a `java.util.function.BinaryOperator<T>`, which is a function that takes two parameters of the same type and returns a result of that same type:

```
public static <T> List<T> (List<T> list1, List<T>, 
                    BinaryOperator<List<T>> converter) { 
    return converter.apply(list1, list2);
}
```